# Excel formula stopped working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a program that dynamically creates excel workbooks based on queries from a database. Among several others, there are these two worksheets. The first lists information by component in each of several projects. The second sheet lists all of the employees and their assigned hours per week for the year in each component by project. So I worked up this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(OFFSET('User Breakdown'!$B$3,0,0,COUNTA('User Breakdown'!$B:$B),1)=A7)*(OFFSET('User Breakdown'!$C$3,0,0,COUNTA('User Breakdown'!$C:$C),1)=B9)*(OFFSET('User Breakdown'!$E$3,0,0,COUNTA('User Breakdown'!$C:$C),52)))
```

To add up all of the hours assigned under each project and component among various users. It worked perfectly. Now it doesn't. It returns a #VALUE! error. We made some changes to the User Breakdown sheet, so I assumed it was because of those changes. We did some formatting, added a column, and filled out the values for the whole year. I went to an older sheet where the formula worked and step by step made all of those changes to see where the formula would start to fail. It never failed. Still works fine. So I went to the new sheet and undid the changes. The formula never started working. I copied both formulas into notepad and sat there comparing them character by character with a coworker. They are identical. I copy pasted the sheet name and back over the formula (although that would have been a #REF! error not a #VALUE! error). MS help contained the exact same text as the popup only with more formatting and on a very slow page. I separated out the pieces of the formula, and each one calculates individually.

So this leaves me with two options: stab the computer repeatedly (which didn't work), or ask you fine folks what might be the problem.

Comment: it's very complicated if not even impossible to say what's the cause without seeing the workbook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#VALUE!` error probably means that you have some text values in the last range defined by

`=OFFSET('User Breakdown'!$E$3,0,0,COUNTA('User Breakdown'!$C:$C),52)`

does this version work?

`=SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET('User Breakdown'!$B$3,0,0,COUNTA('User Breakdown'!$C:$C),1)=A7)*(OFFSET('User Breakdown'!$C$3,0,0,COUNTA('User Breakdown'!$C:$C),1)=B9)*ISNUMBER(OFFSET('User Breakdown'!$E$3,0,0,COUNTA('User Breakdown'!$C:$C),52)),OFFSET('User Breakdown'!$E$3,0,0,COUNTA('User Breakdown'!$C:$C),52))`

If it does that's just because that version will ignore any text values - you may still need to ascertain where the text values occur in case they should be numbers included in the total.....

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I still have no idea where the text values came from. I'll investigate further.